# Why do C# destructors need to have XML Documentation?

Tags: c#, finalizer

I like to keep the comments and Xml documentation of my C# code fairly minimal.  Preferring to make the code self-documenting where possible instead.

But the C# compiler gives a warning if I don't put an Xml comment on a destructor of a public class.  Why is this?

Is there some useful information I should be putting into Xml comments here, which I've not been doing.  I've never found the need to read the comments on a destructor myself.  Is the compiler just being over-zealous?

Comment: @Reed: By the way, it's a "destructor" in C#, not a finalizer. See section 10.13 of the specification, which begins "*A destructor is a member that implements the actions required to destruct an instance of a class.*"  Many people believe this to have been a bad choice of name, and I agree. "Finalizer" would have been better. But they are called destructors, in C#, not finalizers.

Comment: @Reed Microsoft disagree I think: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx

Comment: @Reed: It depends which version of the spec you read. The ECMA spec refers to finalizers, but the MS spec still refers to destructors.

Comment: I suspect your point is that because no client can ever call the d'tor directly it seems unneccessary to write doc comments?

Comment: @Eric: Thanks - I'm used to looking at the ECMA spec.  As Jon mentioned, it states it differently.

Comment: @Steve: Yes, and I don't think I've ever had a destructor without a Dispose, in which case all the interesting code would be in the Dispose.  I can understand why Dispose would be documented.

Comment: The only time you ever want a destructor in C# is when you have an entirely new kind of unmanaged resource.  For example, data access classes that hide away SqlConnections should _not_ need destructors. They only need IDisposable. Destruction is covered by the original SqlConnection.  However, if you're building a whole new ADO.Net provider for a new kind of database that doesn't rely on existing providers, then you do need a destructor.

Answer (score 2):

If you turn on XML Doc comments, the compiler will want you to document everything in your API.  The destructor is part of the API, and really should be included.

A destructor should typically only exist on `IDisposable` classes, and having it documented does help signal/remind people to call `Dispose()` on the object, as doing so (if implemented correctly) will significantly reduce GC pressure.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect, although I have no proof, that the warning fires simply because it looks for doc comments on all methods that are not marked as private. I doubt there is a specific rule that destructors specifically need comments.

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to anyone who uses your code to know exactly what it is that the finalizer does.  In other words if you are working with a slew of unmanaged resources it would be helpful if the documentation clearly outlined what your class does with those resources when they are freed.

Answer (score 0):

It insists on that because your class is public and the C# destructor ends up overriding a [protected method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize.aspx), which is visible from outside your assembly.

Comment: No, in C# the visibility of Finalize() is even less than private. Same for the destructor, you cannot call/see it even from inside the class.

Comment: Your assembly might be reused by other languages than C#.